# Nslocalization for iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I have 3 to set languages in my project. So when user select one language of my 3 language application works in that specific language. I have tried to use `Nslocalization` but not found any solution. I have Xcode 4.5. Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should add Localizable.string file for Localization